# Angular form control array of checkboxes

Tags: angular, checkbox, formgroups

I have an array of objects that I would like to use as a form control as a list of checkboxes. If a checkbox is checked, it adds the checkbox value to the form control (which is a list and starts out empty). This is what I have so far:

```
userAddForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4)]),
  lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4)]),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
  Validators.email]),
  username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4)]),
  password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(5)]),
});
```

When the component is initialized, I instantiate the array and build it from a data source, and then I am thinking I have to do this:

```
this.userAddForm.addControl(this.locations);
```

But then what would I do in my template to make this work?

Comment: JasonCat, You need choose the way you want to store the "locations". the locations are store in an array of string with the selected values only? an array of boolean true/false as large of all your possibles location? a string separate by commas? Then you need choose if you want use a mat-multiselect https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection, a simples checkbox or else. Remember a FormControl can store "anything", not only numbers and string else arrays or arrays of object

Comment: Is their no way to display a list of checkboxes instead of a select input field, and whenever one is checked it appends it's value to an array (or removes it from the array if it is unchecked)?

Answer (score -1):

can you provide stackblitiz from your code??

you can try binding your checkbox formcontrol as:

```
bindCheckBoxGroup(array) {
    const group = [];
    const group1 = [];
    array.map((l) => {
      group1.push(new FormGroup({
        key: new FormControl(l.name),
        value: new FormControl(l.name.toLowerCase()),
        status: new FormControl(l.value),
      }));
    });
    const formControlArray = new FormArray(group1);
    group.push(new FormGroup({
      options: formControlArray,
      selectedOptions: new FormControl(UserService.mapItems(formControlArray.value)),
    }));
    formControlArray.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      group[0].controls.selectedOptions.setValue(this.mapItems(v));
    });
    return group[0];
  }

mapItems(items) {
    const selectedItems = items.filter((l) => l.status).map((l) => l.key);
    return selectedItems.length ? selectedItems : null;
  }
```

Comment: This is comment. not an answer.

Comment: i cannot comment

Comment: Then try answering question